# Wondering why code used to read file isn't printing out results

Tags: java, string, file-io

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class HW3 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner filereader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String type;
        float cost;

        try {
            filereader = new Scanner(new File("Items.txt"));
            while(filereader.hasNextLine()) {
                String CurrentLine = filereader.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer SplitLine = new StringTokenizer(CurrentLine, "[|]");
                name = SplitLine.nextToken();
                cost = Float.parseFloat(SplitLine.nextToken().trim());
                type = SplitLine.nextToken();
                System.out.println(name + " " + cost + " " + type);
            }
            filereader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

The bracket above is supposed to be in code format.

Currently this is what me and a friend have, however his is running perfectly fine (just different
variable names) and mine errors out it just outputs nothing (using Eclipse IDE).

I'm wondering if it's just a random IDE problem as sometimes similar happened with this before, or a mistake with my code.

Posting the text file below after each item is a new line `Item 1: Light Bulb |5.99|Type X`
Next line would be Item 2:

```
Item 1: Light Bulb |5.99|Type X 
Item 2: Wifi Security Camera |20.99|Type X 
Item 3: 3 and 1/2 Inch Nails |.45|Type Y 
Item 4: 1 and 1/2 Inch Nails |.20|Type Y 
Item 5: Candles |19.99| Type Z 
Item 6: Pumpkin Decoration |7.99| Type Z
```

Comment: You are ignoring any exceptions. I suspect a `FileNotFoundException` is being thrown which you will never find out about since your `catch` block is empty.

Comment: @f1sh I'm relatively new to using the FileNotFoundException just wondering what I could add to the catch block to potentially solve the issue. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Just remove the try/catch completely, so that you will know when something goes wrong.